# Trying to get child records from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Am in the angular-fire-seed tutorial stage and experimenting with messages and child posts, for some bizarre reason I cannot see the children when I explicitly try to display them, but can see it when expanding on the parent node in the console. These messages display properly in the html where I have the ng-repeat, so I know I am getting the messages at least, albeit childless.

I thought angularfire-seed utils might be chopping or slicing some children so I reverted to straight firebase

This is what I have:

```
Code:
-----
var url = fbutil.ref() + "/messages/";
var ref = new Firebase(url);

var sync = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

console.log(sync);          //this I can see as a proper $firebaseArray object
console.log(sync.length);   //this displays as 0 even though length is 3 in object above
console.log(sync[1]);       //displays as undefined 

Data:
----
messages/id1/text
        /id2/text
        /id2/post
        /id3/text
```

Thanks in advance for pointing out what I am mis-assuming !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be falling for the common asynchonisity problem.

This is your code fragment:

```
var sync = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

console.log(sync);        //this I can see as a proper $firebaseArray object
console.log(sync.length); //this displays as 0 even though length is 3 in object above
console.log(sync[1]);     //displays as undefined
```

The call to `$asArray()` doesn't return a Firebase array immediately, since the data may take some time to come down from the Firebase servers. So instead it returns the **promise** of a Firebase array, something that in the future will contain your data.

By the time you inspect the out of `console.log(sync)` in the console, the data will have downloaded so it is (as you say) a proper synchronized array. But when the `console.log(sync.length)` line runs, the data probably hasn't downloaded yet.

You can wait for the data to be downloaded with the `$loaded()` method. So:

```
var sync = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

console.log(sync);
sync.$loaded().then(function(sync) {
  console.log(sync.length); 
  console.log(sync[1]);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer from [AngularFire Accessing child element methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230921/angularfire-accessing-child-element-methods)

short answer: once assigned to a JS var, it is a POJO, not a $firebase object anymore.

Comment: It's great that you found my answer helpful, but I don't think it's the cause of your problem. I'll write up an answer here too.