# Wait for loaded data and then return in AngularFire 0.9.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a form which I want to be sent only if the user provided a valid access key (`$scope.access_key`) - and each key can be used only once.

In my controller I have a following method:

```
$scope.verifyAccess = function() {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+'/keys');
    var sync = $firebase(ref);  
    $scope.keys = sync.$asArray();
    var success = false;
    $scope.keys.$loaded( function(KEYS) {
        for( var i = 0; i < KEYS.length; i++ ) {
            var e = KEYS[i];
            console.log(e.key + " " + e.used);
            if( e.key === $scope.access_key && e.used == false ) {
                e.used = true;
                $scope.keys.$save(i);
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( success ) {
            console.log("success");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("failure");
            return false;
        }
    });         
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
$scope.addSurvey = function() {
    if( $scope.verifyAccess() ) {
        // do something
        alert("OK");
    }
};
```

When I call `$scope.addSurvey()` I see "success" in my log (and the database is modified properly), but `alert("OK")` doesn't fire.

If I don't use `$loaded`, method returns immediately and doesn't wait for the data to be loaded and processed. On the other hand, if I use `$loaded`, it doesn't seem to return anything at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keenan has the right of it. In addition to his answer, see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268446/trying-to-get-child-records-from-firebase/26277382#26277382, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297654/passing-variable-in-parent-scope-to-callback-function/26299662#26299662 and probably a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded), `$loaded()` "Returns a promise which resolves after the initial records have been downloaded from Firebase." You can chain functions on that promise using `.then`, or just passing 1 callback as an argument, as you did above. However, you're returning from that callback, not from `$scope.verifyAccess`.

You're going to have to morph this into more asynchronous code. There's a few ways to do this; you could make `$scope.verifyAccess` update some `hasAccess` variable to `true` & then return a promise. Then `$scope.addSurvey` would look something like:

```
$scope.addSurvey = function() {
  $scope.verifyAccess()
    .then(function(){
      if( hasAccess ){
        // do something
        alert("OK");
    });
};
```

The above approach requires use of a promise library, which is valuable to learn and become familiar with. Alternatively, you can let `$scope.verifyAccess` take a callback that's executed once it actually verifies if a user has access:

```
$scope.verifyAccess = function(callback) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+'/keys');
    var sync = $firebase(ref);  
    $scope.keys = sync.$asArray();
    var success = false;
    $scope.keys.$loaded( function(KEYS) {
        for( var i = 0; i < KEYS.length; i++ ) {
            var e = KEYS[i];
            console.log(e.key + " " + e.used);
            if( e.key === $scope.access_key && e.used == false ) {
                e.used = true;
                $scope.keys.$save(i);
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( success ) {
            console.log("success");
            callback();
        } else {
            console.log("failure");
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed the first approach and it works great. Additionaly, I used [these examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to modify `verifyAccess()` so that it returns a promise.

Comment: Great answer Keenan. @machaerus, returning the promise works great for a lot of use cases. It allows you to create some sophisticated chains, use it in routes with `resolve` and do other amazing async constructs.